# Unit testing code that writing to a file without using mock frameworks

Tags: unit-testing, junit

I want to write a unit test a feature that Interact with the file system (write to a file).
the solution I have adapted to the moment it is creating a temporary folder, using: **@Rule** annotation and **TemporaryFolder** class. This file will be deleted after the unit test. But this solution has two drawback:

- It is not a good practice to interact with the file system during a TU (similarly to the database and network)
- If a problem has occurred and the files in the temporary folder are not properly closed, this directory will be never deleted.

There's there a way to write a unit test to test a feature that Interact with the file system without utilization of mock frameworks like Mockito?

Comment: If you *had* used Mockito you wouldn't have interacted with the filesystem either way. Either you access it, or you mock it (either via Mockito, or writing the plumbing code yourself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, accessing the file system is something that doesn't follow the idea of *pure* unit tests; but: writing to some local files is still much faster than network / database communication.

And when you leave those directories in place after a fail, you also have direct access to all output that was created; which might be helpful for debugging purposes.

Finally: then you can always trigger a "wipe" of your temp directories on other layers too - thereby minimizing the chance of "leftovers".

Long story short: be *pragmatic* here.

If your tests are still simple and helpful when writing to the local file system; then keep it that way. Don't change your working approach just to blindly follow rules that other people put in place.

On the other hand, if you (and your team members!) really feel uncomfortable about the current solution; then determine your option space and decide if you want to change something in your setup.